# The 1.0/sites API call is not returning all stackexchange sites

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, api

[Version 1](http://stackauth.com/1.0/sites/) of the [/sites](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites) API call does not appear to be returning all sites currently in the StackExchange network.

Compared to calling [version 2](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/sites?pagesize=400) of the API with a large page size, the list of sites in v1 is getting truncated after Salesforce Meta.

Answer (score 6):

From the [API 1.1 docs](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/usage):

> The V1.x family of APIs is obsolete, having been replaced by the V2.x family.
>
> New applications should use V2.1, and existing applications should migrate to V2.1 as well.
>
> Existing API V1.x endpoints are still supported, but **we are no longer creating new ones for new Stack Exchange sites**. (emphasis mine)

Presumably, Salesforce was the last Stack Exchange site created when API 1.0/1.1 was still active, but newer sites are not getting their API endpoints created.

The original announcement on StackApps regarding the deprecation of API 1.x can be found [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/3439/deprecating-api-v1-x). (Oddly enough, it looks like Libraries was supposed to be the last site created with an API 1.0 endpoint, but the deadline was apparently extended).